# Is there a way to find out if someone downloaded files from my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, security, file-sharing

Problem: I was in a big meeting and logged in to a wlan with everyone else. Everyone had a Mac. Like 50 people or so. After the meeting I saw that in my sharing settings, my whole Mac HD was completely shared for everyone. Now, is there some logfile that could show me if someone did download private stuff from my Mac during that meeting?

Comment: How did that happen? It's likely that they couldn't read the files in your user folder apart from Public due to permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFP (file sharing) access should be logged in:

```
/Library/Logs/AppleFileService/AppleFileServiceAccess.log
```

SSH based logins and general security information goes into:

```
/var/log/secure.log
```